# What are the different ways to access artifactory?

Tags: artifactory

Can someone enumerate the different ways in which people can access artifactory OSS. I want to plugin all access with secure AD login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Artifactory supports AD out of the box (even in OSS version). Look for LDAP in secutiry section.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Assume that I have set the LDAP security. Can someone point their pom to artifactory repo and resolve artifacts from it even though they dont have permission to do it? POM is one way to access virtual repository. What are other ways one can access it ? Say UI, api etc. Can you enumerate on that?

Comment: If the User doesn't have the needed permission he, naturally, won't be able to resolve the artifacts, no matter the way. Generally you are right, there are two ways to access Artifactory - the UI and REST API. Build and DI tools (like Maven, Ivy, Grade) are all using REST.